# Update Mongodb collections object. Node.JS MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Part of the function which creates records in the DB:

```
exports.postForm = function(req,res){
    var User = db.model("User", dbUser);
    var newUser = new User({
         id: "todo",
         role: "inactive",
         sessionid : "todo",
         activeKey : authKey,
         salt: "todo",
         password  : req.body.password,
         profile: {
               name      : req.body.firstname,
               surname   : req.body.surname, 
               username  : req.body.displayname, 
               email     : email,
               twitter   : "todo",
               facebook  : "todo",
         }
    newUser.save(function(err, newData){....}
```

Now, if an existing user changes personal information, changes need to be made in the DB.
For example, `username`, which is inside the `profile` object, needs to be changed.
How can I update `profile` without changing system fields, like `sessionID` or `role`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [`update` method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/).

`save` will simply replace all the content of a document. `update` allow you to only update parts that have changed.